# Spring controller for universal request?

Tags: spring

I have a needs where I have created an application which is configured to defaults. I have controller where the request is coming and processing is happening. Now i need to create another controller to handle some other type of sub-service . because these two are not related, I am planning to create a new one. now my problem is with the call urls. the first controller is configured as:

```
@Controller  
public class Controller1 {  

    @Autowired private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;  
    @Autowired private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;  

}
```

and the second one which I want to add is :

```
@Controller  
@RequestMapping("publish")  
public class Controller2{  

    @Autowired private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;  
    @Autowired private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;  

}
```

now what i want is that **for all the requests, the call should go to the first controller**, and for **only calls related to publish, it should go to second controller**. i tried this, but it doesn't work. please let me know what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for the request mapping

```
@RequestMapping("/")
```